# How to pass django form parameters from a template to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I am trying to extend the snippet:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/
  (which works very well)
enabling a formset to be extended dynamically with javascript

I would like to extend this pattern to enable me to have multiple formsets on a page and dynamically extend each one separately.

The jquery dynamic-tables are extending and contracting all right on the page, but the new form in the formset is always from formset1, even when the formset2 form's 'add' button is used

html template snippet (one of these tables for each formset, e.g. sourceformset):

```
<div id="{{ sourceformset.prefix }}">
<table id="source_id_forms" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" class="recordtable">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <!-- {{ sourceformset.as_p }} -->
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% for form in sourceformset.forms %}
  <tr id="{{ form.prefix }}-row" class="dynamic-form">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ form.as_p }}
       <a id="remove-{{ form.prefix }}-row" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteForm(this, {{ sourceformset.prefix }})">delete property</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr><td></td><td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addForm(this, {{ sourceformset.prefix }})">add property</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

javascript functions

```
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
}

function addForm(btn, prefix) {
    var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    var row = $('.dynamic-form:first',prefix).clone(true).get(0);
    $(row).removeAttr('id').insertAfter($('.dynamic-form:last',prefix)).children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    $(row).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $(row).find('.delete-row').click(function() {
        deleteForm(this, prefix);
    });
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount + 1);
    return false;
}
```

It appears to me that the addForm button is not able to differentiate between the two django formset instances and just defaults to the first one

all help and advice gratefully received

mark

Comment: I have found a more solid approach, based on https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset which is maintained and up to date and delivers what i need very helpfully